# Show a colored border frame when capturing display with MediaDevices.getDisplayMedia()

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, screensharing, get-display-media

I would like to keep the user aware that their screen is still being captured by my web app.
How can I display a colored overlay border to remind them of this ?

See illustration

[image]

Comment: have you got any solution for this?

Comment: @SyamKumar no sorry not yet please let me know if you do